# How can I export multidimensional matrix from julia in Excel?

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

I have a multiple dimensional matrix in my result for example x[I, j, k, t]. How can I export it from Julia in Excel?
For example I have this matrix in Julia. I coded a location inventory vehicle routing model in Julia. That is the optimum routing matrix. I want to export it in Excel.

```
`xx
x: 4 dimensions:
[1,:,:,:]
  [1,1,:,:]
    [1,1,1,:]
      [1,1,1,1] = 0.0
      [1,1,1,2] = 0.0
      [1,1,1,3] = 0.0
    [1,1,2,:]
      [1,1,2,1] = 0.0
      [1,1,2,2] = 0.0
      [1,1,2,3] = 0.0
    [1,1,3,:]
      [1,1,3,1] = 0.0
      [1,1,3,2] = 0.0
      [1,1,3,3] = 0.0
  [1,2,:,:]
    [1,2,1,:]
      [1,2,1,1] = -0.0
      [1,2,1,2] = 0.0
      [1,2,1,3] = 0.0
    [1,2,2,:]
      [1,2,2,1] = 0.0
      [1,2,2,2] = 0.0
      [1,2,2,3] = 0.0
    [1,2,3,:]
      [1,2,3,1] = 0.0
      [1,2,3,2] = 0.0
      [1,2,3,3] = 0.0
  [1,3,:,:]
    [1,3,1,:]
      [1,3,1,1] = -0.0
      [1,3,1,2] = 0.0
      [1,3,1,3] = 0.0
    [1,3,2,:]
      [1,3,2,1] = 0.0
      [1,3,2,2] = 0.0
      [1,3,2,3] = -0.0
    [1,3,3,:]
      [1,3,3,1] = 0.0
      [1,3,3,2] = 0.0
      [1,3,3,3] = 0.0
  [1,4,:,:]
    [1,4,1,:]
      [1,4,1,1] = -0.0
      [1,4,1,2] = -0.0
      [1,4,1,3] = -0.0
    [1,4,2,:]
      [1,4,2,1] = -0.0
      [1,4,2,2] = -0.0
      [1,4,2,3] = -0.0
    [1,4,3,:]
      [1,4,3,1] = 0.0
      [1,4,3,2] = 0.0
      [1,4,3,3] = 0.0
  [1,5,:,:]
    [1,5,1,:]
      [1,5,1,1] = -0.0
      [1,5,1,2] = -0.0
      [1,5,1,3] = -0.0
    [1,5,2,:]
      [1,5,2,1] = -0.0
      [1,5,2,2] = -0.0
      [1,5,2,3] = 0.0
    [1,5,3,:]
      [1,5,3,1] = -0.0
      [1,5,3,2] = 0.0
      [1,5,3,3] = 0.0
  [1,6,:,:]
    [1,6,1,:]
      [1,6,1,1] = -0.0
      [1,6,1,2] = -0.0
      [1,6,1,3] = -0.0
    [1,6,2,:]
      [1,6,2,1] = -0.0
      [1,6,2,2] = -0.0
      [1,6,2,3] = 1.0
    [1,6,3,:]
      [1,6,3,1] = 1.0
      [1,6,3,2] = 1.0
      [1,6,3,3] = -0.0
[2,:,:,:]
  [2,1,:,:]
    [2,1,1,:]
      [2,1,1,1] = 0.0
      [2,1,1,2] = 0.0
      [2,1,1,3] = 0.0
    [2,1,2,:]
      [2,1,2,1] = 0.0
      [2,1,2,2] = 0.0
      [2,1,2,3] = 1.0
    [2,1,3,:]
      [2,1,3,1] = 1.0
      [2,1,3,2] = 1.0
      [2,1,3,3] = 0.0
  [2,2,:,:]
    [2,2,1,:]
      [2,2,1,1] = 0.0
      [2,2,1,2] = 0.0
      [2,2,1,3] = 0.0
    [2,2,2,:]
      [2,2,2,1] = 0.0
      [2,2,2,2] = 0.0
      [2,2,2,3] = 0.0
    [2,2,3,:]
      [2,2,3,1] = 0.0
      [2,2,3,2] = 0.0
      [2,2,3,3] = 0.0
  [2,3,:,:]
    [2,3,1,:]
      [2,3,1,1] = 0.0
      [2,3,1,2] = 0.0
      [2,3,1,3] = -0.0
    [2,3,2,:]
      [2,3,2,1] = 0.0
      [2,3,2,2] = 0.0
      [2,3,2,3] = 0.0
    [2,3,3,:]
      [2,3,3,1] = 0.0
      [2,3,3,2] = 0.0
      [2,3,3,3] = 0.0
  [2,4,:,:]
    [2,4,1,:]
      [2,4,1,1] = -0.0
      [2,4,1,2] = -0.0
      [2,4,1,3] = -0.0
    [2,4,2,:]
      [2,4,2,1] = -0.0
      [2,4,2,2] = -0.0
      [2,4,2,3] = -0.0
    [2,4,3,:]
      [2,4,3,1] = 0.0
      [2,4,3,2] = -0.0
      [2,4,3,3] = -0.0
  [2,5,:,:]
    [2,5,1,:]
      [2,5,1,1] = 0.0
      [2,5,1,2] = -0.0
      [2,5,1,3] = -0.0
    [2,5,2,:]
      [2,5,2,1] = 0.0
      [2,5,2,2] = -0.0
      [2,5,2,3] = -0.0
    [2,5,3,:]
      [2,5,3,1] = 0.0
      [2,5,3,2] = -0.0
      [2,5,3,3] = -0.0
  [2,6,:,:]
    [2,6,1,:]
      [2,6,1,1] = -0.0
      [2,6,1,2] = -0.0
      [2,6,1,3] = -0.0
    [2,6,2,:]
      [2,6,2,1] = -0.0
      [2,6,2,2] = -0.0
      [2,6,2,3] = -0.0
    [2,6,3,:]
      [2,6,3,1] = -0.0
      [2,6,3,2] = -0.0
      [2,6,3,3] = -0.0
[3,:,:,:]
  [3,1,:,:]
    [3,1,1,:]
      [3,1,1,1] = 0.0
      [3,1,1,2] = 0.0
      [3,1,1,3] = 0.0
    [3,1,2,:]
      [3,1,2,1] = -0.0
      [3,1,2,2] = 0.0
      [3,1,2,3] = 0.0
    [3,1,3,:]
      [3,1,3,1] = -0.0
      [3,1,3,2] = -0.0
      [3,1,3,3] = 0.0
  [3,2,:,:]
    [3,2,1,:]
      [3,2,1,1] = 0.0
      [3,2,1,2] = -0.0
      [3,2,1,3] = 0.0
    [3,2,2,:]
      [3,2,2,1] = 0.0
      [3,2,2,2] = -0.0
      [3,2,2,3] = 1.0
    [3,2,3,:]
      [3,2,3,1] = 1.0
      [3,2,3,2] = 0.9999999999999996
      [3,2,3,3] = 0.0
  [3,3,:,:]
    [3,3,1,:]
      [3,3,1,1] = 0.0
      [3,3,1,2] = 0.0
      [3,3,1,3] = 0.0
    [3,3,2,:]
      [3,3,2,1] = 0.0
      [3,3,2,2] = 0.0
      [3,3,2,3] = 0.0
    [3,3,3,:]
      [3,3,3,1] = 0.0
      [3,3,3,2] = 0.0
      [3,3,3,3] = 0.0
  [3,4,:,:]
    [3,4,1,:]
      [3,4,1,1] = 0.0
      [3,4,1,2] = -0.0
      [3,4,1,3] = -0.0
    [3,4,2,:]
      [3,4,2,1] = -0.0
      [3,4,2,2] = -0.0
      [3,4,2,3] = 0.0
    [3,4,3,:]
      [3,4,3,1] = 0.0
      [3,4,3,2] = -0.0
      [3,4,3,3] = -0.0
  [3,5,:,:]
    [3,5,1,:]
      [3,5,1,1] = 0.0
      [3,5,1,2] = -0.0
      [3,5,1,3] = 0.0
    [3,5,2,:]
      [3,5,2,1] = 0.0
      [3,5,2,2] = -0.0
      [3,5,2,3] = -0.0
    [3,5,3,:]
      [3,5,3,1] = -0.0
      [3,5,3,2] = -0.0
      [3,5,3,3] = -0.0
  [3,6,:,:]
    [3,6,1,:]
      [3,6,1,1] = -0.0
      [3,6,1,2] = -0.0
      [3,6,1,3] = -0.0
    [3,6,2,:]
      [3,6,2,1] = -0.0
      [3,6,2,2] = -0.0
      [3,6,2,3] = -0.0
    [3,6,3,:]
      [3,6,3,1] = -0.0
      [3,6,3,2] = -0.0
      [3,6,3,3] = -0.0
[4,:,:,:]
  [4,1,:,:]
    [4,1,1,:]
      [4,1,1,1] = -0.0
      [4,1,1,2] = 0.0
      [4,1,1,3] = 0.0
    [4,1,2,:]
      [4,1,2,1] = -0.0
      [4,1,2,2] = 0.0
      [4,1,2,3] = -0.0
    [4,1,3,:]
      [4,1,3,1] = -0.0
      [4,1,3,2] = -0.0
      [4,1,3,3] = -0.0
  [4,2,:,:]
    [4,2,1,:]
      [4,2,1,1] = -0.0
      [4,2,1,2] = -0.0
      [4,2,1,3] = -0.0
    [4,2,2,:]
      [4,2,2,1] = -0.0
      [4,2,2,2] = -0.0
      [4,2,2,3] = 0.0
    [4,2,3,:]
      [4,2,3,1] = -0.0
      [4,2,3,2] = 0.0
      [4,2,3,3] = -0.0
  [4,3,:,:]
    [4,3,1,:]
      [4,3,1,1] = 0.0
      [4,3,1,2] = 0.0
      [4,3,1,3] = -0.0
    [4,3,2,:]
      [4,3,2,1] = 0.0
      [4,3,2,2] = 0.0
      [4,3,2,3] = 1.0
    [4,3,3,:]
      [4,3,3,1] = 1.0
      [4,3,3,2] = 0.9999999999999996
      [4,3,3,3] = 0.0
  [4,4,:,:]
    [4,4,1,:]
      [4,4,1,1] = 0.0
      [4,4,1,2] = 0.0
      [4,4,1,3] = 0.0
    [4,4,2,:]
      [4,4,2,1] = 0.0
      [4,4,2,2] = 0.0
      [4,4,2,3] = 0.0
    [4,4,3,:]
      [4,4,3,1] = 0.0
      [4,4,3,2] = 0.0
      [4,4,3,3] = 0.0
  [4,5,:,:]
    [4,5,1,:]
      [4,5,1,1] = -0.0
      [4,5,1,2] = -0.0
      [4,5,1,3] = 0.0
    [4,5,2,:]
      [4,5,2,1] = 0.0
      [4,5,2,2] = 0.0
      [4,5,2,3] = -0.0
    [4,5,3,:]
      [4,5,3,1] = -0.0
      [4,5,3,2] = -0.0
      [4,5,3,3] = 0.0
  [4,6,:,:]
    [4,6,1,:]
      [4,6,1,1] = -0.0
      [4,6,1,2] = -0.0
      [4,6,1,3] = -0.0
    [4,6,2,:]
      [4,6,2,1] = -0.0
      [4,6,2,2] = -0.0
      [4,6,2,3] = -0.0
    [4,6,3,:]
      [4,6,3,1] = -0.0
      [4,6,3,2] = -0.0
      [4,6,3,3] = -0.0
[5,:,:,:]
  [5,1,:,:]
    [5,1,1,:]
      [5,1,1,1] = -0.0
      [5,1,1,2] = 0.0
      [5,1,1,3] = 0.0
    [5,1,2,:]
      [5,1,2,1] = -0.0
      [5,1,2,2] = 0.0
      [5,1,2,3] = -0.0
    [5,1,3,:]
      [5,1,3,1] = 0.0
      [5,1,3,2] = 0.0
      [5,1,3,3] = -0.0
  [5,2,:,:]
    [5,2,1,:]
      [5,2,1,1] = 0.0
      [5,2,1,2] = -0.0
      [5,2,1,3] = -0.0
    [5,2,2,:]
      [5,2,2,1] = -0.0
      [5,2,2,2] = -0.0
      [5,2,2,3] = 0.0
    [5,2,3,:]
      [5,2,3,1] = 0.0
      [5,2,3,2] = 0.0
      [5,2,3,3] = -0.0
  [5,3,:,:]
    [5,3,1,:]
      [5,3,1,1] = 0.0
      [5,3,1,2] = -0.0
      [5,3,1,3] = 0.0
    [5,3,2,:]
      [5,3,2,1] = 0.0
      [5,3,2,2] = -0.0
      [5,3,2,3] = 0.0
    [5,3,3,:]
      [5,3,3,1] = 0.0
      [5,3,3,2] = -0.0
      [5,3,3,3] = -0.0
  [5,4,:,:]
    [5,4,1,:]
      [5,4,1,1] = 0.0
      [5,4,1,2] = 0.0
      [5,4,1,3] = 0.0
    [5,4,2,:]
      [5,4,2,1] = 0.0
      [5,4,2,2] = -0.0
      [5,4,2,3] = 1.0
    [5,4,3,:]
      [5,4,3,1] = 1.0
      [5,4,3,2] = 0.9999999999999996
      [5,4,3,3] = 0.0
  [5,5,:,:]
    [5,5,1,:]
      [5,5,1,1] = 0.0
      [5,5,1,2] = 0.0
      [5,5,1,3] = 0.0
    [5,5,2,:]
      [5,5,2,1] = 0.0
      [5,5,2,2] = 0.0
      [5,5,2,3] = 0.0
    [5,5,3,:]
      [5,5,3,1] = 0.0
      [5,5,3,2] = 0.0
      [5,5,3,3] = 0.0
  [5,6,:,:]
    [5,6,1,:]
      [5,6,1,1] = -0.0
      [5,6,1,2] = -0.0
      [5,6,1,3] = 0.0
    [5,6,2,:]
      [5,6,2,1] = 0.0
      [5,6,2,2] = 0.0
      [5,6,2,3] = -0.0
    [5,6,3,:]
      [5,6,3,1] = 0.0
      [5,6,3,2] = -0.0
      [5,6,3,3] = -0.0
[6,:,:,:]
  [6,1,:,:]
    [6,1,1,:]
      [6,1,1,1] = -0.0
      [6,1,1,2] = 0.0
      [6,1,1,3] = -0.0
    [6,1,2,:]
      [6,1,2,1] = -0.0
      [6,1,2,2] = -0.0
      [6,1,2,3] = -0.0
    [6,1,3,:]
      [6,1,3,1] = -0.0
      [6,1,3,2] = -0.0
      [6,1,3,3] = -0.0
  [6,2,:,:]
    [6,2,1,:]
      [6,2,1,1] = -0.0
      [6,2,1,2] = -0.0
      [6,2,1,3] = -0.0
    [6,2,2,:]
      [6,2,2,1] = -0.0
      [6,2,2,2] = -0.0
      [6,2,2,3] = 0.0
    [6,2,3,:]
      [6,2,3,1] = -0.0
      [6,2,3,2] = -0.0
      [6,2,3,3] = -0.0
  [6,3,:,:]
    [6,3,1,:]
      [6,3,1,1] = -0.0
      [6,3,1,2] = -0.0
      [6,3,1,3] = -0.0
    [6,3,2,:]
      [6,3,2,1] = -0.0
      [6,3,2,2] = -0.0
      [6,3,2,3] = -0.0
    [6,3,3,:]
      [6,3,3,1] = -0.0
      [6,3,3,2] = -0.0
      [6,3,3,3] = -0.0
  [6,4,:,:]
    [6,4,1,:]
      [6,4,1,1] = -0.0
      [6,4,1,2] = -0.0
      [6,4,1,3] = -0.0
    [6,4,2,:]
      [6,4,2,1] = -0.0
      [6,4,2,2] = -0.0
      [6,4,2,3] = -0.0
    [6,4,3,:]
      [6,4,3,1] = -0.0
      [6,4,3,2] = 0.0
      [6,4,3,3] = -0.0
  [6,5,:,:]
    [6,5,1,:]
      [6,5,1,1] = 0.0
      [6,5,1,2] = 0.0
      [6,5,1,3] = -0.0
    [6,5,2,:]
      [6,5,2,1] = -0.0
      [6,5,2,2] = -0.0
      [6,5,2,3] = 1.0
    [6,5,3,:]
      [6,5,3,1] = 1.0
      [6,5,3,2] = 0.9999999999999996
      [6,5,3,3] = 0.0
  [6,6,:,:]
    [6,6,1,:]
      [6,6,1,1] = 0.0
      [6,6,1,2] = 0.0
      [6,6,1,3] = 0.0
    [6,6,2,:]
      [6,6,2,1] = 0.0
      [6,6,2,2] = 0.0
      [6,6,2,3] = 0.0
    [6,6,3,:]
      [6,6,3,1] = 0.0
      [6,6,3,2] = 0.0
      [6,6,3,3] = 0
```

.0`

Comment: Can you please specify how you want the data to look like in Excel?

Comment: `xx
x: 4 dimensions:
[1,:,:,:]
  [1,1,:,:]
    [1,1,1,:]
      [1,1,1,1] = 0.0
      [1,1,1,2] = 0.0
      [1,1,1,3] = 0.0
    [1,1,2,:]
      [1,1,2,1] = 0.0
      [1,1,2,2] = 0.0
      [1,1,2,3] = 0.0`
I have this matrix in my code that i=1...6, j=1...6, k=1...3, t=1...3

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it to a .csv file which will be easily imported in an Excel sheet.
Working code for `Julia 1.1.0` and `JuMP 0.19.0`

```
 x = [0.0 for _ in 1:6, _ in 1:6, _ in 1:3, _ in 1:3]

 using CSV
 using DataFrames

 function arr_to_csv(x, outputstring)
     df = DataFrame(i = Int[], j = Int[], k = Int[], t = Int[], x = Float64[])
     sizes = size(x)

     for i in 1:sizes[1]
         for j in 1:sizes[2]
             for k in 1:sizes[3]
                 for t in 1:sizes[4]
                     push!(df, (i, j, k, t, x[i,j,k,t]))
                 end
             end
         end
     end
     df |> CSV.write(outputstring, header = ["i", "j", "k", "t", "value"])
 end

 arr_to_csv(x, "./4dim-x.csv")
```

Replace `x` with your matrix

Comment: It has this error,
`arr_to_csv(xx, "./4dim-x.csv")
ERROR: size (and "end" syntax) not implemented for JuMPArray objects.Use JuMP.size if you want to ac
cess the dimensions.
Stacktrace:
 [1] arr_to_csv(::JuMP.JuMPArray{Float64,4,NTuple{4,UnitRange{Int64}}}, ::String) at C:\Users\admin\
Desktop\modelwithtriangle\97.12.25\mainnnmodel.juliarc.jl:119
 [2] macro expansion at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\JuliaPro-0.6.4.1\pkgs-0.6.4.1\v0.6\Atom\src\rep
l.jl:118 [inlined]
 [3] anonymous at .\<missing>:?`
it seems, the error is for size function

Comment: @SomayehEsmaeili This is working on Julia 1.1.0 and JuMP 0.19.0. It might be possible this isn't working for you because you're on a different version. Can you please tell me what are your Julia and JuMP versions ?

Comment: it is Julia 0.6.4.1. Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: ,I cant use excel for my results in this version? should I update the Julia?
Thanks